# installing php/apache from source

Tags: apache-2.2, php5, repository

I've just made a new instance via AWS EC2 - opting for the most recent stable release of ubuntu - 11.04.  I now need to install the latest versions of PHP and Apache. I've run an `apt-get update` etc..

Unfortunately I require an even newer version of PHP - which isn't available via `apt-get`.

I've tried compiling php 5.3.8 via source, but I've had lots of problems.

My question is, should I continue down this route? Or is there an alternative? I've seen posts on here about alternative repository lists.. Can someone point me in the right direction, that would be a massive help! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [dotdeb](http://www.dotdeb.org/2011/08/30/php-5-3-8-is-available/) repository.

Comment: dotdeb has packages for debian, not for ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I do he following (for PHP 5.2.x)

./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php --with-apxs2=/usr/local/servers/apache/bin/apxs
--with-pgsql=/usr/local/servers/postgresql --enable-pdo --with-pdo-pgsql=/usr/local/servers/postgresql --with-pear --without-mysql

make
make install

You'll possibly want to add any number of the following options among others depending on your needs:

--enable-xml --enable-libxml
--with-pcre-regex
--enable-trans-sid
--enable-sockets
--with-iconv
--enable-mbstring
--enable-ctype
--with-zlib
--with-ssl
--enable-simplexml --enable-dom --enable-spl